# django database crashing with large text field entry

Tags: python, django, heroku

So I am writing a python based django webapp and using heroku to host it.

My app is crashing with the error:

```
Request Method: POST
Django Version: 1.8.1
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value: autocommit cannot be used inside a transaction
```

And I am trying to allow the user to upload a large ~10,000 character text file and then save it in the database. Here is my relevant HTML:

```
    <form action="add_resume" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

    E-mail:<br>
    <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
    Upload Plain Text (.txt) Version of Resume (PDF coming soon but not now!):<br>
    <!--<input type="file" name="upload" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel" />-->
    <input type="file" name="resume" accept="text/plain" />
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

And here is the relevant python server side code:

```
def insert_resume(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {'success': 'no sire'}
        return render(request, 'insert_resume.html', context)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get("email", "")
        #resume_text = request.POST.get("resume", "")

        file = request.FILES['resume']
        resume_text = file.read()         # Reads file
        #with this line in use and the one below it commented out everything works fine
        #resume_text = "yoooo this is an awesome resume!!!"
        resume_text = str(resume_text)

        #it prints out the correct text here
        logger.info(resume_text)

        context = {'success': email}
        r = Resume(email=email, resume_text=resume_text)
        r.save()

        return render(request, 'insert_resume.html', context)
```

And here is my model:

```
class Resume(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    resume_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    when = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
```

So it works fine when I used a hardcoded bit of text in there but I can't get it to work with the uploaded text. Which when I log is the correct text. Am I doing something wrong with the model or how I'm getting the POST data?

Thanks!

Comment: using `Psycopg` for `PostgreSQL` by any chance?

Comment: No I am using sqlite3 though I have psycopg installed

Comment: @deja-vu scratch that, the exception location is: Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py in _set_autocommit, line 214

Comment: and as another update when I increase the hard-coded string to ~2500 characters it gives me the same error.